# Create colour range with corrplot in R

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I have searched google and stack overflow for an answer to my question in R but can't find a suitable one.
I have a matrix, which I import into R, I then use corrplot to plot. My question is that I have three correlation groupings:

1: 0-<0.5

2: >0.5-0.7

3: >0.7

I want one colour for each grouping, so red for group 1, blue for group 2, and green for group 3

Is there a way to do that?

here is some dummy data:

```
library(corrplot)

data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)
set.seed(0)
corrplot(M,type='upper',method = "square",addCoef.col = "white")
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
data(mtcars)
M <- abs(cor(mtcars)) # absolute values 
M[M<=0.5]=-1          # your conditions
M[M>=0.7]=1
M[M != -1 & M != 1]=0
my.col <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue", "green"))  # your colors 
set.seed(0)
corrplot(M,type='upper',method = "color", col = my.col(3), cl.pos = "n")
```

see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html

Comment: do you want to display the numeric correlation coefficients or is this solution enough?

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I have been searching for. Adding coefficients would be nice and also a legend to match the conditions would be great if possible? Sorry not to savvy when it comes to things like this. @Lukas Weber

Comment: Sorry, is there also a way to colour the first diagonal with white? I tried this to change: df2[df2==0.0]=-0.5 and then followed with: df2[df2<=0.5]=-1 but just changes the first one to all -1 again.

Comment: I thought about it but everything additional would be hacky since you would need two  matrices as input which I think is not supported by standard corplot functionality, sorry!